# Concerning the Riemann mapping theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G, U$ be simply-connected, open, non-empty subsets of $\mathbb{C}$. 
Let $z_0 \in G, w_0 \in U$. Does there exist a biholomorphism $f: U \to G$ such that $f(w_0) = z_0$? Is it unique?

I know that by Riemann mapping theorem it is enough to take $f_1 : U \to \mathbb{D}$, $f_2: G \to \mathbb{D}$ and biholomorphism we are looking for is $g = f_1 \circ f_2^{-1}$. But I think it is not unique, because we can always take $\bar{g} = f_1 \circ r \circ f_2^{-1}$ where $r$ is a rotation of disc. Is my answer correct?

Comment: Fine, except that there are a bit more than rotations which maps D biholomorphically onto D (just google on e.g. "mobius transformation unit disk")

Comment: Almost but not quite. It's clear from your argument that you intend $f_i$ to map the special point ($z_0$ and $w_0$ respectively) to $0$, but you don't explicitly state that. And $G$ and $U$ aren't specified as _proper_ subsets of $\mathbb{C}$. If one is proper but the other isn't, no such $f$ exists by Liouville's theorem. If both are proper or both are $\mathbb{C}$, such an $f$ exists (and is not unique), but your argument only deals with the proper case. The argument for $G = U = \mathbb{C}$ is similar, but more elementary.